# .load and .slideDown does not work first time it runs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im trying to load external html documents inside a div with .load and .slideDown, but the first time I click on a thumb is doesnt run the animation after the first time it works fine.

If I put a alert between .load and .slideDown the first time it shows the content before I dismiss the alert, after that it waits until i dismiss the alert.

```
$('.thumbs2').click(function() {

var idStr = ("project/"+$(this).attr('id')) + " #box_project2";
    $('#close2').fadeIn(500).css({'display': 'block', 'height': '25px'});


     $('#box_project2').load(idStr,function(){  
                $(this).slideDown('slow', function() {
                });
        $.scrollTo('#gohere',300);


    });

});
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you remove `+ " #box_project2"` from `idStr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the animation that is not working is ".slideDown" It seems fine since you are calling it in the callback. I would try to see if the fadeIn is messing it up by setting it to display block without the fade so it's instant. Also just to make sure, does #box_project2 already exist prior to this being executed? (sorry I would comment but I do not have enough reputation)

Comment: Yes probably something with the fade in, but what i find wierd is that the content shows up before i dismiss the alert if i add one. Yes #box_project2 is the div where the content should expand and is also wrapping all content in the separate files.

Comment: Hm I agree that does sound weird that the alert isn't preventing the content from animating. Have you tried putting a callback in the fadeIn to run the .load?

Comment: No, I doubt that would fix it though, just ignore the whole #close line since its for another element and i remove it when testing.

Comment: Good lord, solved it after sitting with it for like 5 hours. .hide solved it $('#box_project2').hide().load(idStr,function(){